# Pd Series datetime convert to datetime in format

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime

I have a series of date and time data in one column , cannot figure it out how to change timestamp to datetime in format given (from %Y/%m/%d %H:%M:$S.%f to %Y/%m/%d %H:%M), what I'm showing below are my sheet ,code, outcome and my attempts.

Here's the data

[image]

I have this

```
dataset_train =  pd.read_excel('2btc_usdt.xlsx',sheet_name=0)
datelist_train = list(dataset_train['datetime'])
print(datelist_train)
```

Outcome

```
[Timestamp('2017-08-17 13:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-08-17 14:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2017-08-17 15:00:00.005000'), Timestamp('2017-08-17 16:00:00.010000'), Timestamp('2017-08-17 17:00:00.015000'), Timestamp('2017-08-17 18:00:00.020000'), 
Timestamp('2017-08-17 19:00:00.025000'), Timestamp('2017-08-17 20:00:00.030000'), Timestamp('2017-08-17 21:00:00.035000'), Timestamp('2017-08-17 22:00:00.040000'), Timestamp('2017-08-17 23:00:00.045000'), Timestamp('2017-08-18 00:00:00.050000'), 
Timestamp('2017-08-18 01:00:00.055000'), Timestamp('2017-08-18 02:00:00.060000'), Timestamp('2017-08-18 03:00:00.065000'), Timestamp('2017-08-18 04:00:00.070000'), Timestamp('2017-08-18 05:00:00.075000'), Timestamp('2017-08-18 06:00:00.080000'), Timestamp('2017-08-18 07:00:00.085000'), Timestamp('2017-08-18 08:00:00.090000'), 
Timestamp('2017-08-18 09:00:00.095000'), Timestamp('2017-08-18 10:00:00.100000'), Timestamp('2017-08-18 11:00:00.105000'), Timestamp('2017-08-18 12:00:00.110000'), Timestamp('2017-08-18 13:00:00.115000'), Timestamp('2017-08-18 14:00:00.120000'), 
Timestamp('2017-08-18 15:00:00.125000'), Timestamp('2017-08-18 16:00:00.130000'), Timestamp('2017-08-18 17:00:00.135000'), Timestamp('2017-08-18 18:00:00.140000'), Timestamp('2017-08-18 19:00:00.145000'), Timestamp('2017-08-18 20:00:00.150000'), 
Timestamp('2017-08-18 21:00:00.155000'), Timestamp('2017-08-18 22:00:00.16..............
```

What I have tried

```
#Attempt no1

datelist_train = list(dataset_train['date'])
datelist_train = [dt.datetime.strptime( date, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M").date() for date in datelist_train]
#it just convert list to series and not changing the format

#Attempt no2
datelist_train = list(dataset_train['datetime'])
datelist_train = pd.to_datetime(datelist_train,unit='ms')
#i get message: unit='ms' not valid with non-numerical val='2017-08-17 13:00:00'
```

Comment: First, datetime is a data type (structure), not a format (as in what is used to represent date/time in a string). Then, your dataframe's 'datetime' column already is of data type datetime (its elements are pd.Timestamp). It seems you want to floor to the minute (strip seconds etc.) - you do that like `dataset_train['datetime'].dt.floor('min')`. Is that what you need?

Comment: Hi , yes this is what i need (cut off the msecond), Thank you helping the society !

Answer (score 2):

Tried out your problem and below code solved it:

```
dataset_train = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Downloads\Book 1.xlsx', sheet_name=0 )
print((dataset_train['timestamp']))
dataset_train['DATE'] = dataset_train['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'))
print(dataset_train['DATE'])
```

Comment: you do not want to use `apply` here - `dataset_train['datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')` is what you want - more readable and efficient.

Comment: @FObersteiner, tried your changes as well and yes it works. Just wanted to know the reason of not using .apply is because it will do the conversion cell level. is that correct?

Comment: yes, via the `dt` accessor, you can directly call the vectorized method. Actually, I'd prefer to use `dt` methods because I think they are more readable, not primarily for the efficiency (unless you have really large datasets maybe).

Comment: Thanks guys! I think i will go for apply() here in my situation.